# Different alignment with enumitem in relation to the font used?

Tags: fonts, vertical-alignment, packages, enumitem

If we use this MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\sffamily\textbf{[\arabic*]}{\,\color{black}{\small\faCompactDisc}}, 
noitemsep]
\item \emph{antisimmetria}: $[A,B] = -[B,A]$; 
\item \emph{bilinearità}: $[A,B + C] = [A,B] + [A,C]$
\item \textit{commutatore di un prodotto}: $[A,BC] = B[A,C] + [A,B]C$
\item \textit{identità di Jacobi}: $[A,[B,C]] + [C,[A,B]] + [B,[C,A]] = 0$. Da notare la permutazione circolare dei tre operatori, cioè $[A,[B,C]] - [[A,B],C] = [B,[A,C]]$. 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

with the sans serif font by `LaTeX` default, the numeration alignment `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]` and `[4]` is satisfied. In fact, as you can see from the two vertical green lines, there are the left-right alignment.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Into my book in addition to [`newtxtext`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtx) package font (clone of Times New Roman) I use [`URW-classico`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/classico) package font, but the left alignment (vertical red line) is missed. See the image below:

[image]

*How do I fix this problem?*

**EDIT 1** This is the output using the @Rmano's code by comment: `\sffamily\textbf{[\makebox[1em][r]{\arabic*}]}`.

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you please add how do you use the fonts that make this fail? I seems that the problem is simply that the "1" in the new font is smaller than "2", but I can't check it... in that case using `\sffamily\textbf{[\makebox[1em][r]{\arabic*}]}` for your numeric label should suffice.

Comment: @Rmano Hi :-) Must I edit my code with urw-classico? :-( I hope that I have understood you. I use `\usepackage{classico}` in my long structure to compilate my very long book.

Comment: According to the README `classico.sty` offers only proportional figures. The comment by @Rmano should suffice for enumerations.

Comment: @RalfStubner Hi Ralf, welcome.  What is the mean of "only proportional figures"?

Comment: Tabular vs. proportional figures: https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/proportional-vs-tabular-figures

Comment: @Rmano See my recent edit. Thank you very much.

Comment: so use the makebox version as in your edit, but with a smaller width than 1em

Comment: Hello and good afternoon! Off-topic. Why do you use both `emph` and `textit` commands in the same environment?

Comment: @manooooh Ciaooooo :-). There many mistakes that I have not seen immediately. Thank you for your comment...and +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the figures in the font are proportional, and not of fixed size, this is expected. You can use a fixed box, with a width equal to the "widest" number in your list:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newlength{\boxw}\settowidth{\boxw}{\sffamily\textbf{8}} % largest number in the list!
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\sffamily\textbf{[\makebox[\boxw][r]{\arabic*}]}{\,\color{black}{\small$\bullet$}}, 
noitemsep]
\item \emph{antisimmetria}: $[A,B] = -[B,A]$; 
\item \emph{bilinearità}: $[A,B + C] = [A,B] + [A,C]$
\item \textit{commutatore di un prodotto}: $[A,BC] = B[A,C] + [A,B]C$
\item \textit{identità di Jacobi}: $[A,[B,C]] + [C,[A,B]] + [B,[C,A]] = 0$. Da notare la permutazione circolare dei tre operatori, cioè $[A,[B,C]] - [[A,B],C] = [B,[A,C]]$. 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

You can also choose if you want the number right-, left-, or center-aligned by using the second optional parameter of `\makebox` (`r`, `l`, `c`).

*Notice* — I don't have all your fonts, so I changed the fancy disk into a bullet here... (and the accented letter have disappeared because I compiled with plain `pdflatex` without loading the correct encoding package).

Comment: Approved ...very nice! I wish you all the best.